# Apply autofill for more than 1 ROW else do not apply

Tags: excel, vba, macros

What's the neatest way of applying Autofill if the ROW count is more than 1?
I use the below line and it's working. However, if there's an instance where there is only 1 count ROW in column "I", there will be an error.

```
Sheets(1).Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Are you speaking of autofilling a J2:J1 range?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly reference the [Range.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) worksheet property for all [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Range.Cells properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx). You cannot rely on the implicit reference to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).

```
with Sheets(1)
    .Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("J2:J" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
end with
```

You might find the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) easier to code.

```
with Sheets(1)
    .Range("J2:J" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
end with
```

The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) passes the parent worksheet reference to all `.Range` and `.Cells` that have the prefix period (aka *full stop* or `.`).

Answer (score 0):

I have used copy and paste method to do autofill function. 
You can use paste special as values or formula as per yourrequirement. It is another way of doing auto fill

```
Sub test11()
Dim L As Long

L = Sheets(1).Range("J1:J" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).Count

   With Sheets("Sheet1")

       .Range("J1").Copy

        ' Change Range as per your requirement and paste function as per your requirement

        .Range("J2:J" & L).PasteSpecial xlValues

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: The `Range("J1:J" & L)` might need a `.`.

Comment: It is working for rows count of 2 or more in column "I". However, if there is only 1 entry in the column I (not including the header), this error appears: "AutoFill method of Range class failed".